# Asserts in Protractor not getting updated values

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to write a protractor test for my angular js application.But I am facing some issues. My code is something like this:

```
describe('Login test', function() {

var username = element(by.model('username'));
var password = element(by.model('password'));
var submitButton = element(by.id('submitbutton'));
var isUserValid = element(by.model('isUserValid'));
var message = element(by.model('message'));

beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('my url');
});

it('should validate user', function() {
    username.sendKeys('xxxxx');
    password.sendKeys('yyyy');

    element(by.id('submitbutton')).click();

    expect(message.getText()).toEqual('true');
    expect(isUserValid).toEqual(true);
```

});
});

When I launch test, browser launches and I can see login fields being populated with the values I have passed in test, and call goes to restful webservice deployed on server. But asserts are not getting satisfied.
In my controller code, I am updating scope variable 'isUserValid' to true($scope.isUserValid=true;) and variable 'message' to 'true'($scope.message='true';). But in test both assert fails.Error message for first assert shows that '' is being compared to 'true'.Error message for second assert shows that null is being compared to true.When I print these values on console,'isUserValid' is shown as null while 'message' is shown as 'false'

Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: You are doing end-to-end testing, you should not assert controller scope variables. Imagine yourself a real user, how would you understand that you've successfully logged in? (probably a URL change, or you see a authorized-only page..)

Comment: Thanks for reply.So I was wrong in asserting scope variables. I need to test for something like URL change.

Comment: Yes, look at your app from a user's perspective. Test your scope variables in unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be running into an issue with redirection after the login. Try to wait until you've been redirected to the destination url and then do the assertions.

```
it('should validate user', function() {
    username.sendKeys('xxxxx');
    password.sendKeys('yyyy');

    element(by.id('submitbutton')).click();

    browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return (/PART_OF_URL_WHEN_LOGGED_IN/).test(url);
        });
    }, 10000).then(function () {
        expect(message.getText()).toEqual('true');
        expect(isUserValid).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried with the code provided above by finspin. But I am getting time out issue:
  Error: Wait timed out after 10000ms

Comment: Did you replace the PART_OF_URL_WHEN_LOGGED_IN with the actual url? What string did you put there exactly?

Comment: I put a part of the actual url...return (/landingPage/).test(url);

Comment: And are you actually redirected to the URL with the landingPage string in it within 10 seconds?

Comment: yes...when I manually test my app on browser it navigates to the target page within no time.